# VBA code that changes the background color of a form after update

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need some code that when a check box is unchecked it will change the background color of my form and return it back to its original color when checked. The code i have for the check box currently locks a combo box when a value is chosen. Example below

```
Private Sub AccessKeyNo_AfterUpdate()
If MsgBox("Do you want to assign Access Key " & Me.AccessKeyNo & "?", _
        vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Me.GuestAccessKeyID = Me.AccessKeyNo

    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    Me.AccessKeyNo.Requery
    Me.AccessKeyNo = Null

    Me.MyCheckBox = IsNull(Me.GuestAccessKeyID)
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

In a standard module (not the form module -- the scope of the constants would be limited to form, thus you wouldn't be able to reuse them):

```
Public Const colorBlue_Cornflower = "15714765"
Public Const colorTan_Encarnacion = "11398133"
```

Now in the module for the form:

```
Dim colorThis as String, booWhatever as Boolean

booWhatever = Me.MyCheckBox  ''Use of the variable can prevent problems

If booWhatever Then
     colorThis = colorBlue_Cornflower
Else
     colorThis = colorTan_Encarnacion 
End If

subFrm.Form.Section(acDetail).BackColor = colorThis 
subFrm.Form.Section(acHeader).BackColor = colorThis 

subFrm.Form.Repaint
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me where the Public Const colorBlue....would go in my code?

Comment: It just needs to go in the header area of a standard module.  NOT a form module, and I'm sorry for not making that clear.  It's only a convenience to assign the Constant, but since I'm applying this change to other forms, really it's more than just convenience.  You may need some clarification on "subFrm." as well ...