# Highlight the first row of continuous form not the current?

Tags: ms-access, formatting, conditional-statements

I am using a continuous form showing customer data  as subform. When I make an insert of new record  through the parent form the subform requeries and shows the new record as the first row courtesy of the customerDate field which is in descending order.
I want to keep this first row always highlighted i.e change the back color of all the fields only for this row.. How can i achieve this..Thank You in adavance.

I have made my form data to be descending order always hence i  am trying to use this method of getting the first record color changed  .. but still it does not work but if I remove from Boxname.BackColor the BackColor then it gets changes to the RGB values but if keep the BackColor it does not work...

```
Set rs = Me.testSubform.Form.Recordset
 With rs
.MoveFirst
 'Me.frmEventLogDataSubform.Form.BoxName.BackColor = lngRed
 Forms!frmBoxEventProcess!frmEventLogDataSubform!BoxName.BackColor = RGB(65, 138, 179)
 End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Try Conditional formatting if your using serial numbering for the subform then highlight based on serial one. if you want to do it by date then set it as expression and if the date is the max then it will show in a different colour. If you are not sure how to do that post back Refer below link for VBA Code for BackColour
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422239/vba-code-that-changes-the-background-color-of-a-form-after-update

Comment: thank you for the response. I was playing with conditional formatting. But whats the expression to find the max date in the conditional formatting?